# Regex question using IIS7's URL Rewrite module

Tags: regex, iis-7, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using URL Rewrite module in IIS7 and using the User Friendly URL Rule template.

I'm trying to get URLs like:

```
Something/param1/something/param2/something/param3/something/something2/ etc.etc.
```

to rewrite to

```
SomethingEnd.aspx?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something/something2& etc.etc.
```

Using the templates, it automatically generates something like:

```
^SomethingEnd\.aspx$
```

to redirect to

```
Something/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}/{C:5}/{C:6} etc.
```

and the reverse to be

```
^Something/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

to be

```
SomethingEnd.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}
```

My problem is, how can I make it dynamic? Though there is a finite amount of params I have in my query string, I really don't want to make, for example, if I have 6 params, 6 separate rewrite rules (and the reverse applied).

I tried

```
^Something/([^/]+)*/?$
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`.

---

**EDIT**

Just as an example, in javascript, you can use this:

```
"Something/param1/something/param2/something/param3/something/something2/".split(/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)/)
```

And this returns an array:

```
["", "Something", "param1", "/", "something", "param2", "/", "something", "param3", "/", "something", "something2", "/"]
```

So, you need just a loop to get correct information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use split using the URL Rewrite Module. I want to keep most of the URL rewriting to server side as much as possible.